# Can't convert object of type java.lang.Long to type(Model class); Fetching Data from firebaseDatabase android kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am using Firebase Database to populate a recyclerview. and i'm facing problem in fetching data.

the error

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.Long to type com.massino.pfeadelramzi.models.Meuble

my code:

```
var mdatabase : DatabaseReference?=null
var listMeubles = mutableListOf<Meuble>()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_liste_meuble3_d)

    mdatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Bureau")
    mdatabase!!.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            for (sna: DataSnapshot in snapshot.children){
                val lis: Meuble? = sna.getValue(Meuble::class.java)   //THE PROBLEME IS HERE 
                listMeubles.add(lis!!)
            }
            mon_recycler.setHasFixedSize(true)
            mon_recycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@ListeMeuble3DActivity)
            mon_recycler.adapter = MeubleAdapter(listMeubles.toTypedArray()){}
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }
    })
}
```

My data Class Meuble:

```
data class Meuble(val imageResource: Int, val nom: String, val prix: Int,val stock:Int)
```

my Firebase data (now i'm just trying to find a solution so i created just one child

[image]

Code to add data to Firebase

```
button4.setOnClickListener{
            var nomUI = spinner.selectedItem.toString()
            var prixUI = textView2.text.toString().toInt()
            var stockUI=  textView3.text.toString().toInt()

            var databaseref = firebaseDatabase.getReference(nomUI)

            if ( nomUI != null || !TextUtils.isEmpty(prixUI.toString()) || !TextUtils.isEmpty(stockUI.toString())){
                var meuble = Meuble(R.drawable.fauteuille2,nomUI,prixUI,stockUI)

                databaseref.setValue(meuble)
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(this,"Remplissez la case manquante",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
```

Please help to solve this exception.

Comment: May I know why are you using for l?oop? and why are you using recyclerview since you only have 1 data (Bureau)?

Comment: @Ticherhaz now i'm just trying to find a solution, in my project i have 12object(of dataclass Meuble)  so each object have 4 properties, i want to fetch 4 properties to define my recycler view card (each card have 4 properties)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ticherhaz commented: since you only have the properties for one child nodes under `/Bureau`, you should use loop over the child nodes in `onDataChange`.

Right now your loop means that `sna` points to each individual property, and that's why it fails. There is (for example) no way to parse the value of `prix` into a `` object.

The code for when you have a single child is:

```
mdatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Bureau")
mdatabase!!.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        val lis: Meuble? = snapshot.getValue(Meuble::class.java)
        listMeubles.add(lis!!)

        mon_recycler.setHasFixedSize(true)
        mon_recycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@ListeMeuble3DActivity)
        mon_recycler.adapter = MeubleAdapter(listMeubles.toTypedArray()){}
    }

    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
})
```

Comment: no in fact i have 12 object (each one have 4 parametre) but i was trying to find a solution, thank you

Comment: Your screenshot shows a single object under `Bureau`, and *that* is the reason you get the error message you posted.

Comment: no i didn't chang my code or firebase database right now, i just add a the default value into constructor, i did some research on data class and i find that it'll we helpfull to add a default value to handle this kind of error, and it work, i'm bit new so i don't now the exact reason

Comment: Sorry, your solution was the right one for the problem posted here, it just didn't solve my real problem, i didnt describe it well

Answer (score 0):

Error Handling :

So to handle my error:
i had to add a **Default Value** to each **parametre** in the **constructor** of my **Data class** :

```
data class Meuble(val imageResource: Int = -1, val nom: String="", val prix: Int=-1,val stock:Int=-1)
```